# Multiple images in activity causing error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm developing an app that displays a step-by-step process for my company. Each step consist of one image and each activity shows eight to twelve images. I'm now running into the java.lang.outofmemory. It's also listing an android.view.InflateException:Binary xml error. I've resized the images to 360dpi and that only allowed a few more pics before reaching the error again. I also tried increasing the heap size, which did not change the result. Is there another way I should do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go through this first, it will help you - http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can scale down the Image, thus reducing their memory footprint. Also, you could look into certain libraries like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and see if they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

No magic here, i guess the imageview are rendering in full argb mode, so 8 bit * 4 * number of pixels. That's a lot!

How does your activity displays images ?

- If they are in a list, make sure to use recycling. 
  http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html 
  You are interested in the ViewHolder
- If you are using a ViewPager and swipes left/right, make sure to destroy your fragments while you are swiping, so that you can have in memory only 3 images (1 displayed, and 2 next to it).
- If it's none of those, maybe you will have to refactor your layout :(

Last but not least, make sure to resize your bitmap to your exact screen size, as suggested before, Picasso provides a convenient mean to do it with .fit(). It will wait for the imageview to be measured, then resize the downloaded bitmap and fit it in the imageview. You don't even have to worry about networking on main thread, how wonderful !

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()) 
        .load(imageUrl) 
        .fit()
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I've added them to a scrollview for display

Comment: Ok so your scrollview (and the linear beneath it i guess) doesn't care about memory issues. You should rethink your layout to be good and future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is where coding approach matters. How you've implemented it might help us pin point the memory leaks.

But a general practice ( maybe not good one)
Load all Bitmaps in a constant class. ( just once)
Refer infinitely.